# In French is it 10 € or € 10?

Tags: nombres, unités, formatage

In English I always write 'the price is **$10**.
I seem to remember seeing in French it is written as **10 €**.

Which is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, "10 €" is right, not the other way around. They write it in the same order they pronounce it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

The symbol of Euro follows after the number; 10 €.

> - Ça coûte combien ? - (Ça coûte) Dix euro**s** (`10 €`).
> - Combien coûte cette salade ? - Deux euros (et) ving-cinq (centimes) (`2,25 €`).

Note that the space before the currency symbol is required!

Comment: On dira plus souvent : deux euros vingt-cinq. Attention, pas d'espace après une virgule décimale mais espace requis avant une unité monétaire.

Comment: Merci pour le commentaire :-)!

Comment: @jlliagre : J'ai modifié la réponse. Par contre, pourrais-tu m'expliquer 
 cette partie "Attention, pas d'espace après une virgule décimale mais espace requis avant une unité monétaire." ? Je ne comprends pas

Comment: Les ouvrages cités indiquent la forme erronée: `2, 25€` alors que la forme correcte est `2,25 €`.

Comment: De plus, si *euro(s)* est écrit en toutes lettres, il convient d'écrire aussi les valeurs en toutes lettres, donc *dix euros*, *deux euros vingt-cinq*.

Comment: C'est bon. Maintenant je comprends. Je vais corriger la réponse et enlever les liens.  Merci encore !